# Removing bad data from a field but leaving the good data

Tags: sql

I have an issue where is bad data in a column on a table. The good data is always an unspecified number of integers separated by a / and then two characters. The problem is that i have any number of periods, ....., after the two characters.

Examples: `1/JP... or 25/US.. of 100/GB. etc....`

What delete statement would remove the periods (.) but leave everything before the two characters?

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.  Also, the question mentions `delete` -- do you want to actually remove *rows* with "bad" data.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the two characters after the `/` are *not* periods.

If you just want to remove periods, then you can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '.', '')
```

If you want to change the data so there are no periods, then you can use `update`:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, '.', '')
    where col like '%/%.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about SUBSTRING method using CHARINDEX as below-

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = '1/JP...'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str,0,CHARINDEX('/',@Str,0)+3)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was able to use the replace function to remove the periods but after thinking about it I would actually like to eliminate any type of character or number after the /JP. There will always be a forward slash and two alpha characters. How can I remove anything after those two alpha characters? It would look like %/JP and anything after the JP should be removed. The JP could be any number of alpha characters as it is the country of origin.